# What is the purpose of Church Encoding?

Tags: lambda-calculus, church-encoding

Lately I was reading articles about Lambda calculus and Church Encoding, and although I formed a remote understanding of what they entail, I am having trouble finding purpose for using higher-order functions to represent numeric values or lists instead of using numeric values or lists directly.

In programming, performing Lambda calculus on Church-Encoded expressions is extremely taxing on the machine's resources, and just seems like a considerably less efficient technique of doing anything. I find that programmers usually consider it bad programming practice, except from Scheme or Haskell programmers, for odd reasons.

Is there any actual practical reason to use Church encoding? Or is it only useful in theoretical study?

Comment: _["The Church encoding is not intended as a practical implementation of primitive data types. Its use is to show that other primitive data types are not required to represent any calculation."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding)_ Showing this might lead to other abstract developments that have indirect practical consequences, but directly it doesn't seem so.

Comment: "Indirect practical consequences" such as what?

Comment: I mean that sometimes, things "all for the sake of academic research" are proof-of-concepts, supporting the validity of theories that can say, establish some definitive limit to the compactness of the syntax of a given class of languages (_e.g._ syntax can't theoretically use any less than _n_ symbols to achieve a certain range of desired operations), or say, proving that a certain language can _never_ accomplish certain operations. (An analogous example is using some encoding to show that standard regular expressions are finite automations, to support the assertion that

Comment: one cannot match balanced parentheses to an infinite depth. You may say, "Why would anyone use such and such an encoding in the first place?" And the response would be, "We meant to show that it was a finite state machine. Which had other consequences, answering other questions.") I'm not saying I have specific examples for you regarding Church Encoding, which is why I'm commenting. But to be honest, your question has a bit of a rant-y smug tone suggesting you've already

Comment: formed your opinions (_e.g._ you believe Church Encoding useless and stupid), so you may not be receiving answers you'd like. Try to lighten up on your view that anything "theoretical" is only for "academic research and esoteric humour."

Comment: "relatively recent hype regarding functional programming".  Alonzo Church, b.1903.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Analysis of a (formal) language becomes technically simpler the smaller it is. If you can represent, for example, data types as functions (which is what the Church encoding gives you), then you don't need to add data types to your language just to be able to examine how you can manipulate data in it.

For a practical programming language, yes, you most often add bespoke data type support; but you can still define their semantics by reducing them to functions and then using just the semantics of the smaller, data type-less language.

Comment: Is it used for compiler theory due to its simplicity?

Comment: It's useful for the same reason you don't add redundant axioms to mathematical theories.

Answer (score 0):

There is one practical use of Church encodings that has come up recently. The use case is the [programmable configuration language called Dhall](https://dhall-lang.org). In that language, recursion is not allowed, but the language includes all of System F and a bit more. So, Church encoding is possible and is the official way of using recursive data types (e.g., trees, to represent JSON data) in Dhall.

What practical advantages does this bring? Because Church encoding guarantees termination (you cannot ever make an infinite loop), the Dhall language can use the Church encoding to represent some recursive types and code while fully preserving its strong normalization property and guaranteed termination. (Configuration files are guaranteed to never have infinite loops.)